# Angular - Routing not working as expected in dev server

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-router

can someone guide me whats the issue with the below code, when I try to hit route 'c' in local environment it routes to 'c', but in dev server first its going to route 'd' and then to route 'c'

````
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: 'a', component: AComponent },
  { path: 'b', component: BComponent },
  {
    path: 'c', 
    component: CComponent,
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    loadChildren: './modules/c/c.module#cModule'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [Auth],
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    component: BComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'd', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'd', component: DComponent,
        children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'e', pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'e', component: EComponent }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'f',
        loadChildren: './modules/admin/f/f-module#FModule'
      },
    ]
  },
];```
````

Comment: Can you tell us what you mean by `local` environment and `dev server`? What is the difference?

Comment: Local machine (localhost), dev server(ngInx web server)

Comment: If you are still stuck, try to create a Stackblitz, and it will be easier to help. 
There might be some ngInx settings causing this as well? (I have no clue, I am just guessing)